# how to give remote file through middleServer to client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-proxy

problem:
There is a file on a server with an address like http://source.com/file.zip,
I need a code in asp.net mvc or web-form to launch it on http://middleserver.com that when a client browse http://middleserver.com/code?link=http://sourse.com/file.zip , the file.zip to be downloaded to client's local storage with resume capability.
important note:file.zip should not located on middleserver. it should only passes through middleserver. middle server acts like proxy with resuming capability which request a byte range to the source server and flush it to client.
Excuse me for my poor English.

Comment: You can; make a get request to the desired resource from your middleserver.com server, get the response stream, and, use Stream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream).

Comment: You can also configure REVERSE PROXY, it is possible with IIS

Comment: I want to control buffer size and download speed. Does your suggestion cover my required?

Comment: For that, instead of using Stream.CopyTo, you can Read() from the input stream and Write() to Response.OutputStream by chunks. You can invoke Thread.Sleep() between these calls to achieve control (limitation) of bandwidth usage (download speed).

Comment: Please remember; this approach will hold the worker thread until the download finishes.